# compile matlab fmincon() to a dll to be called by c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, dll, matlab-deployment

is it possible (and if so how) to compile matlabs fmincon() to a dll and eventually use it from a c++ code. it would be nice to have a detailed example if this is possible.

thanks in advance.

Comment: use this page: http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, he would need to install Matlab for using the Matlab engine. That costs $. In order to deploy DLL you only need MCR

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Could you clarify that, please? Say they have a program that requires the use of `fmincon`, and they are developing a standalone product. The link above states that `fmincon` is supported for compilation, so why would compiling it to a DLL be a problem?

Comment: My now deleted first comment on this question was stupid.